# Запуск *.bat из *.bat

Tags: bat

Всем привет. Хочу написать код для запуска *.bat из *.bat. Есть батник run.bat он делает запуск вида

```
set SAMPLE_PROPERTIES= -Dsamples.trustAll=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java %SAMPLE_PROPERTIES% -cp "%LOCALCLASSPATH%" -Xmx1024M com.web.Main %ARG%
```

запуск батника из смд все классно работает

```
run.bat com.web.task.Start -url "http://..." -username "..." -password "..." -basic "true"
```

начинаются проблемы если эту команду поместить в другой батник testRun.bat и запустить так:

```
call run.bat com.web.task.Start -url "http://..." -username "..." -password "..." -basic "true"
```

Вылетает екзепшн

```
 ERROR: Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.
```

Подскажите почему вылетает екзепшн и как исправить. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: А у вас там прямо так и написано `%ARG%`?